# Why my android client cannot receive string message from winsock c++ server?

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets

I am trying to build an android app that communicates with a c++ server running on windows using TCP sockets. I successfully sent a string from the app to the server but I cannot do the other way around. Please help me because I have been trying with this issue for a while now.

Android Client:

```
String mystr="Hello World...";
char[] buffin=new char[128];
String input =null;
Integer count = 0;
class TextRcv extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
{

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Sending a string (WORKING)
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.1.5",8889);
            DataOutputStream oos= new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeBytes(mystr);
            //oos.writeBytes(String.valueOf(mystr.length()));//write the length of the string first
            //byte[] bufferout=mystr.getBytes();
            //oos.write(bufferout, 0, bufferout.length);
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Recieving a String (Not working)
        try {
            BufferedReader in = null;
            if (clientSocket != null)
            {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("samer ","CLIENTSOCKET NULL");
            }

            if (in != null)
            {
                count=in.read(buffin);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("samer ","BUFFERREADER NULL");
            }

            if(count>0)
            {
                input=new String(buffin,0,count);
            }
            if (clientSocket != null) {
                clientSocket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("samer count: ",String.valueOf(count));//RETURNS 0 !!
            Log.i("buff samer: ", String.valueOf(buffin));//Returns garbage
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer count) {
        super.onPostExecute(count);

        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(count),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

The 'count' always returns 0 despite the fact that on the windows c++ server side it says that it has successfully sent the 25 bytes.

C++ Winsock Server:

```
int  main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    int valread;
    int iSendResult;
    char * recvbuf;
    char *recvstr;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    recvbuf = (char*)malloc((recvbuflen + 1) * sizeof(char));
    recvstr = (char*)malloc((recvbuflen + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char* AndroidID;
    char *sendbuf = "Client: sending data test";

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);

        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();

        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();

        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();

        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();

        return 1;
    }

    if (ClientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Start Receving" << endl;

        //------Start Receiving
        //-----------------------------------
        int lengthofrecv=recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        recvbuf[lengthofrecv] = '\0';//append \0 to use with printf()
        AndroidID = recvbuf;
        printf("AndroidID - %s \n", recvbuf);
        cout << " \n Done ";

        //---Start Sending to android
        //-----------------------------------------
        iResult = send(ClientSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            wprintf(L"send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);

        cout << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Server console output:

> Start Receving
>
> AndroidID - Hello World...
>
> Done Bytes Sent: 25
>
> 0
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: What happens if the Java read code runs before the sending code has sent, does it read 0 bytes or block?

Comment: @RichardCritten: the [`read(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read(char[])) documentation says: "***This method will block until some input is available**, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is reached.*"

Comment: So you are suggesting that the read operation in my code is actually run before the servers sends. Right? If so what do you think I should do? Do I close the socket and reopen it for each read or write operation? Or should I delay before the read operation to give the server some time to put the data on the network? What is the best way to deal with that? (If I understand correctly)

Comment: "*Do I close the socket and reopen it for each read or write operation*" - of course not!  The real problem is that your code is closing the socket before it has a chance to read. You need to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `oos.close()` after sending the initial string to the server.

`DataOutputStream` extends `FilterOutputStream`, and the behavior of its `close()` method is documented:

[FilterOutputStream.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close())

> The close method of FilterOutputStream calls its flush method, and then **calls the close method of its underlying output stream**.

In this case, the "underlying output stream" is the socket's outputStream, and its `close()` behavior is also documented:

[Socket.getOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream())

> Closing the returned OutputStream will **close the associated socket**.

[Socket.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close())

> Closes this socket.
>
> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will throw a SocketException.
>
> **Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use** (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created.
>
> Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.
>
> If this socket has an associated channel then the channel is closed as well.

So, your client is closing the socket connection before it can read the server's reply string.  You need to remove that call to `oos.close()` so yo keep the connection open until you are done reading.

On the server side, simply due to timing, your code may be able to call `send()` and put the reply string into the socket's outbound buffer before the socket detects the disconnect.  The buffer is not actually transmitted by `send()` itself, it is queued to the OS kernel, which will transmit the data in the background.  So `send()` will return success instead of failure if the reply string is buffered before the disconnect is detected.

Comment: You're an absolute legend. Thanks a lot. Worked exactly as you said.